# EmberJS auto loading inverse relations?

Tags: ember.js

I have a model like:

```
var Survey = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

and:

```
var SurveySection = DS.Model.extend({
  survey: DS.belongsTo('survey', {async:true}),
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  help_text: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

If i have a survey object, can I just do `survey.get('survey_section')` to get all the sections associated with a particular survey, because this isn't working? It doesn't even work if I add a `survey_sections: DS.hasMany('survey_sections', {async:true})` to my survey model.

I should add that I'm using fixtures. When I release the app they'll still be used (ie so if the RESTAdapater would fix it, that's not a fix in my case):

```
Survey.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
  {
    "id": 1, 
    "title": "Favourite food"
  }, 
  {
    "id": 2, 
    "title": "Sports"
  }
]
});
```

and:

```
SurveySection.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
  {
    "help_text": "", 
    "id": 1, 
    "survey": 1, 
    "title": "Italian food"
  }, 
  {
    "help_text": "", 
    "id": 2, 
    "survey": 1, 
    "title": "Team sports"
  }, ...]});
```

Is the fixture adapter not able to retrieve related records in the reverse direction like this? If not, will I have to go the laborious route of manually getting the sections with `survey=1`, for example (laborious because I'll have to take this approach throughout my whole app with other models)?

**Update**

Specifically my failing code is (with survey 1):

```
this.get('survey').get('survey_sections').then(function(survey_sections) {
  // survey_sections contains no objects, so objectAt(0) returns undefined.
  survey_sections.objectAt(0).get('questions').then(function(questions) {
    console.log('Set first question ID to ' + self.get('firstQuestionId'));
  });
});
```

As the fixtures show there should be 2 SurveySection objects in survey_sections, but instead none are found.

Comment: You're need to include your code that isn't working in order to get help.  Specifically, are you trying to code something like `section.get('survey')` ?  Realize that this will return a promise.

Comment: @SteveH. i've added my failing code

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to do it, but I had to add the forward relation to the items in the Survey fixture, e.g.:

```
Survey.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
  {
    "id": 1, 
    "title": "Favourite food",
    "survey_sections": [1, 2],
  }, 
  {
    "id": 2, 
    "title": "Sports",
    "survey_sections": [3],
  }
]
});
```

and update the Survey model with:

```
survey_sections: DS.hasMany('survey_sections', {async:true})
```